# C++ std::vector clear all elements

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector

Consider a `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
vec.push_back(1);
vec.push_back(2);
```

Would `vec.clear()` and `vec = std::vector<int>()` do the same job? What about the deallocation in second case?

Comment: I would expect the destructor for std::vector to clean up when the object goes out of scope, however since it isn't created with new, there is no deallocation required.

Comment: Are you using C++11 or newer? The second case actually behaves differently between C++11 and C++03

Comment: Im using c++11.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`vec.clear()` clears all elements from the vector, leaving you with a guarantee of `vec.size() == 0`.

`vec = std::vector<int>()` calls the copy/move(Since C++11) assignment operator , this replaces the contents of `vec` with that of `other`. `other` in this case is a newly constructed empty `vector<int>` which means that it's the same effect as `vec.clear();`. The only difference is that `clear()` doesn't affect the vector's capacity while re-assigning does, it resets it.

The old elements are deallocated properly just as they would with `clear()`.

Note that `vec.clear()` is always as fast and without the optimizer doing it's work most likely faster than constructing a new vector and assigning it to `vec`.

Answer (score 5):

They are different:

`clear` is guaranteed to not change capacity.

Move assignment is not guaranteed to change capacity to zero, but it may and will in a typical implementation.

---

The `clear` guarantee is by this rule:

> No reallocation shall take place during insertions that happen after a call to `reserve()` until the time when an insertion would make the size of the vector greater than the value of `capacity()`

Post conditions of `clear`:

> Erases all elements in the
>   container. Post: `a.empty()`
>   returns `true`

Post condition of assignment:

> `a = rv;`
>
> a shall be equal to
>    the value that `rv`
>    had before this
>    assignment
>
> `a = il;`
>
> Assigns the range
>   `[il.begin(),il.end())` into a. All existing
>   elements of a are either assigned to or
>   destroyed.

Comment: This link says change in capacity is not guaranteed: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/clear/

Comment: @CinCout - That link is to a very poor reference. See this for a better one http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: @CinCout - That's the reference... What are you commenting about exactly? Nobody said `clear` changes capacity, only that move assignment does.

Comment: The cplusplus.com text confused me. When it says not guaranteed, I interpret it as it may or may not change the capacity on calling `clear()`, more like it is left to the compiler implementation. But clearly, that is not the case.

Comment: @StoryTeller I cannot find such guarantee from the standard. Could you point me to it?

Comment: @StoryTeller the only rule that I found that might be interpreted as guaranteeing that `clear` won't change capacity is `No reallocation shall take place during insertions that happen after a call to reserve()
until the time when an insertion would make the size of the vector greater than the value of capacity()` (which you kindly linked), but if that applies to `clear`, then I don't see why it would not apply to move-assignment.

Comment: @StoryTeller I've changed the answer accordingly, thanks.

Comment: @CinCout - One to-the-letter interpretation of the standard is that after you have called `reserve()` the capacity cannot be reduced (as quoted above), so `clear()` must not reallocate. But then if you have never called `reserve()` it might be allowed. It would be a perverse implementation to keep track of calls to `reserve()` just to modify the effects of `clear()`.